# Install OwnCloud with PostgreSQL - Not Authenticating on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, postgresql-9.3, owncloud

Okay all I have tried to follow the instructions online for getting Postgresql to work with OwnCloud install but it still gives me the dreaded "PostgreSQL username and/or password not valid You need to enter either an existing account or the administrator."

I have installed:

- Ubuntu 12.04LTS
- Apache 2.2
- PHP 5.3
- PostgreSql 9.3
- OwnCloud 6.0.3

My web server is hosted on an internal server at 192.168.1.11 and I have Postgresql running on port 3145.

Any tips on getting this to work with Postgresql... Here is my config.php file:

```
$CONFIG = array (
  'instanceid' => 'oc57c67b8ac3',
  'passwordsalt' => '07b04cab4ff3d074dc59fc3ef82650',
  'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => 'www.example.com',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/Cloud/owncloud/data',
  'dbtype' => 'pgsql',
  'version' => '6.0.3.1',
  'dbname' => 'owncloud',
  'dbuser' => 'cloudadm',
  'dbpassword' => 'mypassword',
  'dbhost' => '192.168.1.11:3145',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
);
```

Comment: Is it listening on that ip? Try 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks @Pétur for getting back to me so quickly.  I tried both 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.1:3145 as the dbhost and neither worked.  I have Postgresql listen_addresses = '*' so all ip address should work...:(  ...one things I could be missing there is no accommodation for non-standard ports? so I have to reset postgresql to the standard 5432 port?

Comment: have you provided this `config.php` yourself, or was it created through the setup wizard? The initial version of this file should always be created by the setup wizard. If you've written it yourself, the code creating the database table probably won't be triggered. Also this question would be better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks @RandolphCarter. I solved it by upgrading to the new OwnCloud 7.0 versions and then ran the wizard ..within minutes the install on PostgreSQL worked.   This is revolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @RandolphCarter -- when I upgraded to OwnCloud7.0 I was able to use the wizard, select the PostgreSQL option and enter [serverip]:[Postgresql port number] - e.g. -- 192.1.1.1:1118 and it worked with no problems.  This is closed.

Comment: Where did you enter the port number? I'm struggling with OwnCloud 9 on the same problem :(

Comment: Sorry for long time rely ..port number gets appended to the ip address and colon   i .e  192.168.1.1:3242

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with the same conclusion: `'dbhost' => 'localhost:1234'`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason setup wizard searching localhost and found no IPv6 record in my  pg_hba.conf After add this record it works.

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

or remove ::1 from /etc/hosts should be the same.

```
::1         localhost
```